# Water content in beignet dough

Tags: french-cuisine, doughnuts

When I add the indicated amount of water to my beignet recipe, I end up with humid flour: not enough moisture to form a dough of any kind. It seems apparent to me some minor adjustment to the water is necessary, but I can't find much information on what I should be aiming for. What should the target consistency be? What will the end result be if I add too much, or too little water?

Comment: Are you using a traditional beige dough such as choux pastry or what? Could you say what the ingredients all are and the amounts so we can have a better idea how to help as there are different types of beignets now. Much also depends on where the recipe came from (European vs American).

Comment: Could you post your recipe, please?

Comment: Shamefully, I must admit it's just the Cafe du Monde box mix, which calls for 7 fl. oz of water per 2 cups mix. Though I also solved the mystery: I was assuming the instructions were for the whole box, while they are actually for just half. Still though, I wonder what can be said about the general effects of water content in deep-fried dough like this.

Answer (score 1):

Each country has different flour, and the temperature also has a big influence. You will probably laugh but to find the right consistency of your dough take your earlobe between two fingers...this is the right consistency it is not a joke, my grandmother taught me this and now I am a grandmother